# a question on the remark about relative homology group in Hatcher’s Algebraic Topology

Tags: algebraic-topology

I’m reading hatcher’s algebraic topology, chapter 2 on homology. After defined the relative homology group $H_n(X, A)$, he gives a remark claiming that: ([https://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/AT.pdf](https://pi.math.cornell.edu/%7Ehatcher/AT/AT.pdf) page124 at the bottom)

> The quotient $C_n(X)/C_n(A)$ could also be viewed as a subgroup of $C_n(X)$, the subgroup with basis the singular n simplices $σ: ∆n→X $ whose image is not contained in $A$. However, the boundary map does not take this subgroup of $C_n(X)$ to the corresponding subgroup of $C_{n−1}(X)$, so it is usually better to regard $C_n(X, A)$ as a quotient rather than a subgroup of $C_n(X)$.

I understand the part that “ this subgroup of $C_n(X)$ to the corresponding subgroup of $C_{n−1}(X)$”, since some singular n-simplex do have a part of boundary contained in $A$:

[image]

But I don’t understand the statement “The quotient $C_n(X)/C_n(A)$ could also be viewed as a subgroup of $C_n(X)$, the subgroup with basis the singular n simplices $σ: ∆n→X $ whose image is not contained in $A$”
. How can it be also viewed as this subgroup? They seems not the same. One is a quotient group, the other is a subgroup. And the boundary operator behaves different. What does hatcher’s “viewed as” means?

Thanks!

Comment: a subset $H$ of $G$ is called a subgroup of $(G,*)$ if $H$ also forms a group under the operation $*$. Now, Is it true that $C_n(X)/C_n(A) \subset C_n(X)$???

Comment: @C.F.G so there is an isomorphism between the relative chain group and the subgroup described? I am thinking how a equivalent class in the quotient group is mapped to the subgroup.

Comment: @C.F.G yeah... maybe I understand it now. A quite vague image seems appearing in my mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$C_n(X)$ is the group of linear combinations of singular simplices in $X$, and $C_n(X)/C_n(A)$ is (isomorphic to) the group of linear combinations of simplices where the ones from $C_n(A)$ are not present. (Strictly speaking: every class in $[\sigma] \in C_n(X)/C_n(A)$ has a representative (a sum) without elements of $C_n(A)$ in it.) Put another way: $C_n(X; G)$ is a direct sum of $G$ over all singular simplices and factoring out $C_n(A; G)$ just kills some of the direct summands; the result, the smaller sum, trivially injects into the big one.

As he says, that's not the best way to think of it anyway: taking the boundary may get you from $\operatorname{Sing}(X) \setminus \operatorname{Sing}(A)$ back to $\operatorname{Sing}(A).$

Comment: Thanks. So the key point to see the isomorphism is to kill some some parts of the free abelian group right? Write the sum explicitly does seem to be helpful. So it’s possible to define the boundary operation directly on the subgroup? It’s just no that natural?

Comment: @onriv
I'm not sure I got the first question. Boundary operation is not defined on $\bigoplus\limits_{\operatorname{Sing}_n(X) \setminus \operatorname{Sing}_n(A)
} G$ - this is what Hatcher is talking about.

Comment: I’m thinking is the boundary map defined on the quotient map composing the isomorphism between the quotient space and the subspace gives some map between the subspaces?

Comment: It just doesn’t look like a quotient map? but there is such a map between these subspace chains?

Comment: Oh, it seems if the map defined between the subgroups, it is taking boundary and then kill all the singular n-1 chains in A?

Comment: @onriv If you really want to express $\partial$ in these terms then yes.